# keyman.setDefaultKeyboardForControl(Pelem, keyboard, languageCode); function is not working with iframe element

Tags: keyman, keyman-developer

It is showing warning that 'keymanweb.setKeyboardForControl' cannot set keyboard on iframes.
I want to manually set specific language of keyman on iframe element.
Please help me out to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

While `keymanweb.setKeyboardForControl` [cannot be used with iframes](https://help.keyman.com/developer/engine/web/current-version/reference/core/setKeyboardForControl), you should be able to use a [`controlfocused` event](https://help.keyman.com/developer/engine/web/14.0/reference/events/kmw.controlfocused) event to select a keyboard on entry to the control:

```js
keyman.addEventListener('controlfocused', function(eventProperties) {
  if(eventProperties.target == myIframe) {
    keyman.setActiveKeyboard(...);
  }
  return true;
});
```